# How does one create instance of 2D array in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, multidimensional-array, createinstance

So I have the following and it seems incorrect.

```
var classAsm =  assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(o => o.FullName == "iControl.CommonAddressPort").First();
Array propertyOfPorts = Array.CreateInstance (classAsm, 1,1);
```

What I wanted to achieve is to assign values to propertyOfPorts since there are 2 (address - string, and port - long) such as this one:

```
propertyOfPorts.address = "12.2.2.2";
propertyOfPorts.port = 80;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would first make a class, then use a list.

```
public class PortProperties {
    public String Address { get; set; }
    public long Port { get; set; }
}
```

Then initialize the list:

```
var propertiesOfPorts = new List<PortProperties>();
```

Then add it:

```
propertiesOfPorts.add( new PortProperties {
    Address = "12.2.2.2",
    Port = 80
});
```

Then use it:

```
PortProperties firstPort = propertiesOfPorts[0];
String address = firstPort.Address;
long port = firstPort.Port
```

Using this method, it is easy to define exactly what you want. Otherwise 2D arrays, or 3D arrays get really confusing. For example, maybe for each of those ports I need to define another list of other such information related to that particular port (therefore making this a potential 3D array), I'd just include a list object in the PortProperties class, simple and easy to understand.

```
public class PortProperties {
    public String Address { get; set; }
    public long Port { get; set; }
    public List<String> otherPropList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gerneio, the only thing is that these properties already exist in "iControl.CommonAddressPort" which is a 3rd partly dll (SDK). But I think you opened up and idea for me on how to tackle this.